# can't upload multiple files with multer nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, __dirname + "/uploads/");
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
      fs.readdir(__dirname + "/uploads/", (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
          callback(err);
          return;
        }
        const fileName = `${files.length}_${file.originalname}`;
        callback(null, fileName);
      });
    },
});
  
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
      if (
        file.mimetype == "image/png" ||
        file.mimetype == "image/jpg" ||
        file.mimetype == "image/jpeg"
      ) {
        cb(null, true);
      } else {
        cb(null, false);
        return cb(new Error("Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!"));
      }
    },
    limits: { fileSize: 3000000 },
});
  
app.all("/api/upload-picture", upload.array("files"), (req, res) => {
    fs.readdir(__dirname + "/uploads/", (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
      }
      const lastFileName = files[0];
      sharp(__dirname + "/uploads/" + lastFileName)
        .resize({ width: 512 })
        .toFile(
          __dirname + "/uploads/" + "resized_" + lastFileName,
          (err, info) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err);
              return res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
            }
            fs.unlink(__dirname + "/uploads/" + lastFileName, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                  console.error(err);
                  res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
                }
                console.log("Original image deleted from disk");
            });
            console.log("Image resized and saved to disk");
            res.send({ code: "0", "response": ("localhost:3000/api/uploads/resized_" + lastFileName) });
          }
        );
    });
});
```

i have this code, but when i run it and upload multiple files in a short period of time i get this error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink '/home/emmanuel_macaron/Documents/programinc/trust-social/server/uploads/0_steve.jpg'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: '/home/emmanuel_macaron/Documents/programinc/trust-social/server/uploads/0_steve.jpg'
}
node:_http_outgoing:644
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:644:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/emmanuel_macaron/Documents/programinc/trust-social/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/emmanuel_macaron/Documents/programinc/trust-social/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)
    at /home/emmanuel_macaron/Documents/programinc/trust-social/server/index.js:583:35
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:185:23) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

I tried to upload multiple files in a short period of time with this code but when i do this it doesn't work

random text because stackoverflow is not letting me post this
random text because stackoverflow is not letting me post this
random text because stackoverflow is not letting me post this

Comment: When using multer, you can access the uploaded files using `req.files` array. And if you want perform operations on thoses files you can do something like `req.files.map(file => doSomething(file))`. And about the unlink function, seems like you are providing the wrong path, try using the `file.path` property of the files you want to delete.  And i also  you forgot use `return` at your first `res.status(500)` causing the code to continue and eventually resend another response causing the ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT error

Comment: Only when you upload multiple files? What about single file? Have you set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your HTML form tag?

Comment: Make sure you are sending multiple files and `lastFileName` variable has the value.